# Logic Apps - Inject HTML tag in an HTML table

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Fairly new to Logic Apps and not familiar with all the functions.

I created a simple Logic App that will check an RSS feed every so often, loops every item it finds, takes only certain data (title, summary and URL link), paste them in an HTML table and then send an email with the outcome.

Is it possible to inject an HTML tag in the HTML table?

I tried adding the `<b></b>` tag with some fixed text hoping that I will find some bold text in my email. Instead I just got regular text along with HTML tags.

Here's the code view of my current implementation. I pasted the Create_HTML_table part only.

```
"Create_HTML_table": {
    "inputs": {
        "columns": [
            {
                "header": "Title",
                "value": "@item()['title']"
            },
            {
                "header": "Description",
                "value": "@item()?['summary']"
            },
            {
                "header": "URL",
                "value": "@item()?['primaryLink']"
            },
            {
                "header": "Thumbnail",
                "value": "@item()?['links'][1]"
            },
            {
                "header": "Thumbnail Image",
                "value": "<img src='@item()?['links'][1]' width='200' height='200'>"
            },
            {
                "header": "Test",
                "value": "<b>This text is bold</b>"
            }
        ],
        "format": "HTML",
        "from": "@body('List_all_RSS_feed_items')"
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Initialize_variable": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "Table"
},
```

As you can see I tried with the `<b>` tag but my ultimate goal is to produce a thumbnail and the source of that would be a value from the same RSS feed. I'm getting the image URL (`@item()?['links'][1]`) but the output is plain text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably easier to build this table as a function. You could still use logic apps to build the email send action.

Comment: @AdAstra thanks for comment, again! Would you say it's probably easier in an Azure Function App? From within the email send action I only checked the IsHTML option.

Comment: Well to be fair, I think I would end up doing the entire thing as a function. All the feeds could be stored in a Jason formatted storage blob. This way you could design a ‘flashy’ email as well.

Comment: I just tried the inline code for this also, with a maximum of 1024 characters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code I would probably still go with a function here :)

Comment: @AdAstra yes had a look at that. For that you need an Integration Account associated with the Logic App. I don't think what I'm after is possible. If a simple `<b>This text is bold</b>` is showing as <b>This text is bold</b> even though I'm creating an HTML table, and setting the email as IsHTML, then I don't know. Thanks a lot for your input

Answer (score 1):

I had similar predicament with HTML table, and took guide from [Alex's blog](https://alextofan.com/2019/02/14/flow-how-to-change-the-style-of-your-html-table-in-flow/)
Basically format the table using variables.

Define the style in varStyle as Object

```
{
"cellStyle": "style\"font-family: Calibri; padding: 5x; border: 1px solid 
black;\"",
"headerStyle": "style\"font-family: Helvetica; padding: 5x; border: 1px solid black;\"",
"rowStyleHighValues": "style=\"font-size: 110%; background-color:#ff9c33\"",
"rowStyleLowValues": "style=\"background-color:#fcff33\"",
"tableStyle": "style\"border-collapse: collapse;\""
}
```

Initialize string variable with table header

```
<table style"border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
 <th style"font-family: Helvetica; padding: 5x; border: 1px solid black;">Line#</th>
 <th style"font-family: Helvetica; padding: 5x; border: 1px solid black;">Item</th>
 <th style"font-family: Helvetica; padding: 5x; border: 1px solid black;">Description</th>


</tr>
```

And the apply to table as string, in my case by row

```
            "For_each": {
            "actions": {
                "Append_to_string_variable": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "name": "varHTMLTable",
                        "value": "<tr @{if(equals(items('For_each')?['Order_x0020_Quantity'], items('For_each')?['Received_x0020_Quantity']), variables('varStyle').rowStyleLowValues, if(equals(coalesce(items('For_each')?['Received_x0020_Quantity'],'NULL'),'NULL'),'',variables('varStyle').rowStyleHighValues))}>\n     <td @{variables('varStyle').cellStyle}>@{items('For_each')?['ASN_LineNumber']}</td>\n     <td @{variables('varStyle').cellStyle}>@{items('For_each')?['Buyer_ItemID']}</td>\n     <td @{variables('varStyle').cellStyle}>@{items('For_each')?['Buyer_ItemDescription']}</td>\n </tr>"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {},
                    "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                }
            },
```

And close table parentheses.
[image]

**My  Logic Apps Flow :**

[image: My Logic Apps Flow]

with following output

[image: output]